# Where is the declaration of `scala.Any`?

Tags: scala

I tried to find the declaration of `scala.Any`, but failed. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in `src/library-aux` folder: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library-aux/scala/Any.scala